# bottleneck issue mysql

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have this project auction portal, the problem is sometimes user can't bid or much better word is the request bid **sometimes** takes 2-3 seconds before it can be registered, the conflict is the auction is already closed before the system detects that someone made a bid.

I have added a log to see what is going on, and here is what I found:

```
Bid insert date        |    Auction close date
2012-06-25 14:40:57         2012-06-25 14:40:54
```

As you can see, the auction was already close but the bid was processed 3 seconds late.
Just to clarify, user can't bid if the auction was already closed, so I am sure that the request was made before it closed.

This happen to 1 auction everyday and I don't know what can trigger this problem.
I am using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Can you give a little bit of info as to how your site is hosted? is it just a single LAMP server or do you have multiple servers and if you do what sort of hardware and load balancing are you using. Also info about how much traffic you are getting will help determine if this is a problem with your code or hardware.

Comment: Should we imagine which is your hardware, code, queries you use and so on? Or should we just click on link you provided?

Comment: We are using windows server, I am not familiar with our server specs. But I think it is high enough to support every request. The traffic is not that high yet since there are only less than 200 members and most of them are not active. 

There are running mysql events which are running ever X seconds use to check the status of each auction and whether someone set an auto bid in behalf of the bidder.

I suspect that it is the mysql configuration, but I don't know what to check, I already migrate some tables to innoDB since most of the tables are changing

Comment: Turning the question around, does it matter? If all you care about is that the user submitted the bid before the auction ended then this is presumably fine. If you're just wanting to know what's slowing down your server then the main thing to check would be any mysql statements that take a few seconds to run and might be implicitly locking the table.

Comment: The service time will always be > 0 however small you optimise it to.  So your business logic must cope with this race.  When you insert a bid, add a clause "when now()<close_date" and then use the rows_affected to see if the insert worked.  If not, then the bid was too late.  End of story.

Comment: Yes, I need to make it real time auction. Is there any other way know if the table lock, or why they are queuing up to a single thread? 
Is there a configuration for this kind of behavior aside from selecting the engine type?

Comment: While it's definitely worth tracking down what's locking your tables for performance reasons, it actually seems like this behavior is desirable for a real time auction. In fact you should probably be getting a timestamp at the start of the script and using that for all your calculations since that's going to be the most accurate measure of when the user placed the bid - the user shouldn't get penalized for your server taking too long to put the request through.

Comment: As far as locks go, its probably worth setting your MySQL slow query log to record any queries taking longer than a second or so, since if there is something blocking it, it's obvious taking a few seconds to run. Then next time it happens see if there are any slow queries running on that table when the issue occurs.

Comment: @Braiba I have added a log for both PHP (to see the timestamp when the request was received) and my current MySql log file. And found out that the request was received from the server 2 seconds late after the auction close.

My question now is, is there any other way to prevent this? I mean is there any configuration that I can do so that if there is a bid request from the client, the server should be able to received the request immediately. 

This always happen all the time, I mean no difference between client to server request, but at a random time, sometimes the request are delayed.

Comment: @Rafael is it just a single request or do the delays occur in batches? I would generally expect this to just be an issue with the user's internet connection. You'd have to be really hammering the CPU with something else for PHP to ignore a request for that long.

Comment: I checked the CPU usage and its not even reaching 40%.
One request per bid, 1 - 2 request in every 20 seconds.

Is it possible that the user's internet connect is too slow that's why the request was not received of our server immediately? But all customer are residing in Singapore, and I think the connection here is very stable and the minimum speed I think is not less than 1mb. If I cannot solve this I think I will just add a 1-2 seconds delay before the auction close.

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause is that a user loads the page including a 'bid' button, the auction closes, the button is still there and the action gets executed accordingly. If you'd validate whether the auction is closed *right before insert* this should never happen. The time between a SELECT and the INSERT should not be > 0.1 seconds. I assume you don't validate the status of the auction before adding the last bid.

Comment: As I have mentioned. User won't be able to bid as well as log if the auction is already closed. There is some kind of process(es) which cause a bottleneck that only happen at least once a day or two.. The logic is correct as well as the validations.

Comment: @Rafael It's all very well you saying that the logic is correct, but if you knew what the problem was you wouldn't be asking here, so some elaboration on what checks you're doing might helpful - preferably the actual code if possible.

Comment: @Rafael: that means the time between your last validation and the insert exceeds 3 seconds. I therefore defy your statement that your logic is correct. I at least doubt it slightly.

Comment: It is a mysql function

endtime is the auction end time
timenow is now();

IF endtime > timenow THEN
   /* process the bid */
END IF;

I am doing the same procedure at our test server which is much slower than our production server, however I am not getting the same problem.

I need to know if my table locks when getting the records to update the auction info, but I already change the engine type to innoDB. I'm quite sure that this is no longer logic problem. It is more on DB or apache configuration, but I dont know what to check or to configure.

Comment: @Raphael where exactly are you performing this check relative to the database insert? You said in the question comments that the request was received after the auction had closed, so if it got saved to the database then there clearly *is* an issue with this check.

Comment: I am referring to temporary log table where all bids are recorded, regardless of the condition, except of course if the auction is already closed.

I log the bid request at the start of my source code that process the bid request (.txt), and also to the database (tmp table). The .txt file and tmp table records have exactly the same date and time. 
Meaning there is no bottleneck during processing of bid request.
The issue that I am trying to solve now is how can I get the request immediately, or this is out of my control due to other factors.

Answer (score 1):

2-3 seconds?

How many queries are you running at the point of the bid request? I would imagine:

1) Is the user logged in?
2) Is there account allowed to bid?
3) Is the auction still open?
4) Post the bid

I wouldn't imagine that these 4 queries would take more than a second to run, unless you have terribly written queries. What MySQL DB layer are you using? Have you ensured that your code is as streamlined as it could be? I.e. how often are you opening the database, etc.

If they bid and the auction finishes before their bid is processed, tough cookie. You haven't won. The same thing happens on eBay sometimes, and its just tough. If the problem is that your system is allowing a late bid to win, then you need to revisit your code in that respect. The last bid attempt should most certainly check to see if the auction is still running BEFORE the bid is saved. And this shouldn't take anywhere near a second to do.

Perhaps you should review your table indexes too. Too few and data searching is slow, too many and data insertion speed is affected.

There could be lots of things wrong, from a simple index mistake to a dodgy query/loop/etc.

Comment: I am interested with "how often are you opening the database". I am not familiar with threads and or DB configuration.

I am sure that the queries are well optimized as well as indexes, most of the time, when I try to bid it registered instantly. So meaning the processing is very quick. However at a random time, someone will complain that the user bid but does not registered, and this happen only 1 or 2 times a day. 

I am not sure whether their internet connection, too many open connection or DB config is causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Dont match for the exact closing timestamp, but compare it with the 
(closing time - turnaround_time).

Lets say the closing time is 14:00:00 and a turnaround time for a request is 10 secs. Then if a request is made before 13:59:50 will only be considered.

Comment: Your implementation was a bit different from the specs. I cannot just change it to fix this problem.